# How to remove everything that is outside the eye? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I would like to know how to remove everything that is not in the eye, except the eyebrow.

Comment: Have you tried using a clipping mask?

Comment: Gives an error with clipping mask, says I cant do it! :O

Comment: What does the error say?  Is the graphic that you are trying to clip grouped?  Is the clipping mask on top of the group?  Is the clipping mask a single path? Did you select both the group and the clipping mask before applying it?

Comment: It might be worth while looking online for [tutorials about using clipping masks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viW--j6470w).

Comment: "everything that is not in the eye, except the eyebrow." So you want to remove the cog wheel? Did you try to click on it and press delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments user Billy Kerr suggested a Clipping mask. It should be quite foolproof as long as you do not try to use some internally complex already existing part as your mask, but draw one for that purpose. I crunched together something that slightly resembles your drawing, but has separate colors for easy communication:

[image]

1. Select the orange, green, brown and black part, Group them and arrange the group to back.
2. Draw on top with the pen a new shape -  one single closed path to be used as the clipping mask. Disable snapping temporarily if it is harmful.
3. Select the new shape and the group. Goto Object > Clipping Mask > Make
4. send the clipped group to back

If this doesn't work, your image is more complex than I have guessed. The only way to remove the need to guess is to provide some exact info of the structure of your image. (a copy in outline mode and a screenshot of expanded layer panel for a start)

Comment: Allright, thanks for effort guys! I did it, I cant recall it now, was super sleepy that time- but it just didnt let me do mask or use shape builder while it was colored in, as soon as i did undo until i had only shape of bee, cog and circles - it happened, I managed to  do it just with drawing extra square on top, then i sent it back and managed to use shape builder to leave my desired outcome. Thanks to everyone, who tried to help! By the way it is not the first time, that as soon as I post my issue, I find an answer right away on my own! Funny thing.